# What's the best way to implement a script for tiling windows?

Tags: 11.04, display, window-manager, command-line

I just upgraded to ubuntu 11.04, and I am looking for a good way to tile windows. What I need is just to move window to the left or right half side of the screen, and bind the actions to some keyboard shortcuts. For instance move-window-to-display.sh contains

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 -eq 2 ]
then
    POS="950 0"
    SIZE="967 1031"
else
    POS="0 0"
    SIZE="965 1031"
fi

xdotool windowmove `xdotool getwindowfocus` $POS
xdotool windowsize `xdotool getwindowfocus` $SIZE

exit 0
```

Then ". move-window-to-display.sh 1" moves the window to the left and ". move-window-to-display.sh 2" to the right. However, this code works but not perfectly, because of xdotool I guess, anyway it is not easy to put the windows at the exact position that we want.

So does anyone have a better way to do this? Either by Shell or by other tools... I tried tiling window manager like xmonad, but it seems too complicated to use...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in Compiz, the default window manager.

First, launch [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM)  by pressing <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> or by clicking on the applications icon then typing 'compiz config' and selecting 'CompizConfig Settings Manager'. If it is not installed, the Software Centre will open so you can install it.

[image: launch ccsm]

Then, click on 'Grid' in the window management section.

[image: ccsm]

You can then configure the key bindings for putting the window to either side of the screen.

[image]

Click on the description of each key binding to change it.

[image]

Comment: That is awesome!!!