# Compizconfig Grid doesn't work under Ubuntu as virtual machine

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys, window-manager, virtualization, macosx

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 as virtual machine within Mac.

I have installed VM tools.

The approach in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38087/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-a-script-for-tiling-windows) of `Compizconfig Grid`, which worked in my previous laptop where Ubuntu was not a virtual machine, does not work anymore. I set some shortcut, but no action is launched...

Does anyone know why?

The major functionality I need from `Grid` is tiling windows to left/right side of the screen... Does anyone know any alternative?

PS: I have tried other plugins of `Compizconfig`, for instance, `Move Window` works...

**Edit1:** The desktop environment I am using is `Ubuntu`, not `Gnome`. The unity is `2D` instead of `3D`. It is not a problem for me to change it if that can solve the `Grid` or tiling problem above.

**Edit2 & 3:** I didn't know that Unity2D does not use compiz by default... After installing `gtk2-engines-pixbuf`, I launched `compiz --replace &`in a terminal, that gives:

[image]

And I tried `Grid` once again: bind shortcut `<Control><Alt>g` to `Put Left`, it still does not work.

But as I said before, if I bind `<Control><Alt>g` to `Initiate Window Move` in `Move Window` (either before or after `compiz --replace &`), the shortcut always has an effect...

**Edit 4:** I just enabled `Accelerate 3D Graphics`, which was disabled before... But rerunning `compiz --replace &` in a terminal gives exactly same message as before including 2 `Fatal` for `opengl`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have updated the initial post...

Comment: I have updated the initial post, there is still `Fatal: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap` left, and I make sure that the unity plugin is not ticked. But still `Grid` does not work...

Comment: ... well done for continually updating your question.  I dont have anymore ideas how to get the compiz Grid working in ubuntu-2D.  Have you seen this question - and if so does any of the answers there give you the tiling capability you are looking for? http://askubuntu.com/questions/41566/how-do-i-get-aero-snap-in-unity-2d

Comment: If I change to ubuntu-3D, do you have any other idea for tiling windows?

Comment: ... sorry to return a question with a question - but I thought unity3D was not possible with VMTools - only virtualbox.  If you can run unity3D then does the Grid work? - your question says you've only tested unity2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I get it, *Fatal: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap* means that X server does not support *GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap* API feature, which requires a 3D hardware acceleration.

You can see the previous error message: *Fatal: Software rendering detected* which means that VM has no configured 3D graphics acceleratio card, either because there is no such hardware in your system, or it's not properly configured.

So check out if there is 3D acc. card in the host OS, or not. If there isn't I guess you can't make Grid work. If there is, you should configure your VM to expose 3D acc. card to the guest ubuntu OS.

See [Compiz hadware requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz#Hardware_requirements).

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I have updated my initial post... the `Fatal` problems are still there, do you have any idea?

Comment: What kind of VM do you use? VMWare? VirtualBox?

Comment: I use `VMware Fusion`

Comment: As you can see here(http://www.vmware.com/support/fusion2/doc/releasenotes_fusion_205.html) and here(http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005097) some 3D acc. cards are not supported by VMWare Fusion. 

Finally that post(http://askubuntu.com/questions/122630/3d-acceleration-is-not-possible-for-ubuntu-as-virtual-machine-by-vmware-fusion) states that 3D graphics support for Linux guests is not available currently in VMWare Fusion. 

But you'd better ask VMWare support about that

Comment: I can confirm that enabling 3d acceleration does allow grid to work on Ubuntu 12.04 VM (Workstation 9) under a Windows 7 host (on mba 2011)

Comment: however, the downside with enabling 3d acceleration on a VM, is that desktop spanning (cycling multiple monitors) becomes untenable (perhaps unless you have a very powerful cpu)